# Is asking for the best NoSQL database for case X ok?

Tags: discussion

This question just popped up.

[What is the Best NoSQL backend for a mobile game](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/102/best-nosql-backend-for-mobile-game)

I think it's off-topic and should be closed as it's much more a software recommendation than something comming with data science.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recommendation questions usually work well only when:

- The use case is *specific* (backend/storage/backup for app/website/enterprise)
- The developer requirements are *well-defined* (works with language/library)
- The expected functionality is *clearly described* (provides indexing and O(ln(n)) searches, etc..)

This question does not go into most of this, and hence should be closed.

The subject matter of this question however, IMO is on-topic. Deciding on which database works well for a certain data processing scenario is within the area of data science.